# Send response to previous rest route

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I am having below camel route, currently which is working fine. 
The `reset-route` route is being invoked by rest url hit.

The `reset-route` is working fine, but how do send proper response to rest service.

The response I want to send to Rest URL is the Count of message sent to MQService and if the route goes into  doCatch I would like to send "ERROR" as a string.

I am clueless currently because at the starting of the `reset-route` it's making a call to java bean and getting list of objects which is being split and processed in parallel.
How do count the message successfully sent to MQ?
Where is the end of split ?
Should I be using transactions for post processing after the split ?

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    logger.info("ResetRoute.configure() : tp started configuring camel route.");

    restConfiguration()
            .enableCORS(false)
            .apiContextPath("/api-doc")
            .apiProperty("api.title", "REST Api to Trigger Swap Reset Tranformation.")
            .apiProperty("cors", "false")
            .apiContextRouteId("doc-api")
            .component("servlet")
            .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true");

    rest("/api/")
    .id("reset-api-route")
    .get("/reset")
    .to("direct:resetRoute");

    from("direct:resetRoute").routeId("reset-route")
            .log("Starting reset route")
            .doTry()
                .process(resetProcessor)
                .bean(transactionManager, "beginTransaction()")
                .bean(clientApi, "getResetTransactions(${body},${header.region})")
                .setHeader("transactionSize", simple("${body.size()}"))
                .choice()
                    .when(header("transactionSize").isLessThan(1))
                    .bean(transactionManager, "markSuccess")
                    .stop()
                .end()  //End of choose()
                    .wireTap("{{tp.reset.auditDir}}" + "${header.inXmlFileName}").onPrepare(jacksonProcessor)
                .split(simple("${body}"))
                    .parallelProcessing()
                    .bean(transformationService, "tranform")
                        .wireTap("{{tp.reset.auditDir}}" + "${header.outXmlFileName}").onPrepare(jacksonProcessor)
                    .process(jacksonProcessor).convertBodyTo(String.class)
                    .bean(mqService, "send")
                .end() //End of Split()
                .bean(transactionManager, "markSuccess")
                .transform().constant("SUCCESS")
            .endDoTry() //End of doTry()
            .doCatch(Exception.class)
                .bean(transactionManager, "markFailure").transform().constant("ERROR")
                .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "EXCEPTION: ${exception.stacktrace}")
            .end(); //End of doCatch()
}


This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

> End of Split

```
.split(simple("${body}"))
    .parallelProcessing()
    .bean(transformationService, "tranform")
        .wireTap("{{trade-publisher.reset.auditDir}}" + "${header.outXmlFileName}").onPrepare(jacksonProcessor)
    .process(jacksonProcessor).convertBodyTo(String.class)
    .bean(mqService, "send")
.end() //End of Split()
.bean(transactionManager, "markSuccess")
.transform().constant("SUCCESS")
```

I was under the impression that after the line  `.end() //End of Split()` whatever i invoke it will be invoked only once but in my case  `.bean(transactionManager, "markSuccess")` is being invoked multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the wiretap which transforms your SplitDefinition into a WireTapDefinition. When you do the .end(), you don't end the split but the wiretap. It's quite confusing, but it happens often with camel. You have to check what's your current "xxxDefinition". In your case, doubling the ".end()" should do the trick.

You can play with this little example :

```
package com.example.camel;

import org.apache.camel.RoutesBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.language.tokenizer.TokenizeLanguage;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;


public class CamelApplicationTests extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Test
    public void endingSplitTest() throws InterruptedException {
        template().sendBody("direct:start", "1,2,3");
        getMockEndpoint("mock:inner").expectedMessageCount(3);
        getMockEndpoint("mock:outer").expectedMessageCount(1);
        getMockEndpoint("mock:outer").setAssertPeriod(1000);
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:start")
                    .split(TokenizeLanguage.tokenize(","))
                    .wireTap("mock:wiretap")
                    .end() // Ending WireTapDefinition
                    .log("Nested route : ${body}")
                    .to("mock:inner")
                    .end() // Ending SplitDefinition
                    .log("Outer route : ${body}")
                    .to("mock:outer");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

You can also do the both .end() consecutively, but it looks a bit worse to me.

```
 @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:start")
                    .split(TokenizeLanguage.tokenize(","))
                    .wireTap("mock:wiretap")
                    .log("Nested route : ${body}")
                    .to("mock:inner")
                    .end()
                    .end()
                    .log("Outer route : ${body}")
                    .to("mock:outer");
            }
        };
    }
```